# Using gsub I want to remove white spaces

Tags: r, data-cleaning

```
names(chocolateData) <- gsub("[[:space:]+]", "_", names(chocolateData))
```

I have used this code to omit the white spaces with an underscore but it didn't work. I have reviewed time and want `reviewed_time` but instead, I get `reviewed.time`

Comment: Try `gsub("[[:space:]]+", "_", names(chocolateData))`  Without a small reproducible example using `dput`, it is not easy to suggest\

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use `gsub`, but is a wonderful tool for cleaning up variable names

```
chocolateData <- data.frame("dark chocolate" = "yum", "white chocolate" = "yuck", check.names = FALSE)
chocolateData
#    dark chocolate white chocolate
# 1            yum            yuck

library(janitor)
chocolateData <- clean_names(chocolateData, case = "snake")
chocolateData
#    dark_chocolate white_chocolate
# 1            yum            yuck
```

I highly recomend checking `janitor` out: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/janitor/janitor.pdf

Answer (score 0):

R does not like variable names that contain spaces. You can have them, but they make things weird and require the use of `` ` ``s. Because of that, when some functions create a data frame, they automatically convert spaces in variable names to periods.

I think what's happening here is that when `chocolateData` was created, the variable `` `reviewed time` `` was converted to `reviewed.time`. Since your `gsub` expression only replaces whitespace, the period is not changed.

If this is the problem, the simplest solution is simply to change your expression to replace periods as well:

```
gsub("[[:space:].]+", "_", 'reviewed.time')
[1] "reviewed_time"
```

Another option is to track down the function changing your variable names. The most likely culprit is `read.table` (or it's children `read.csv` and `read.delim`). Try passing the argument:

```
check.names = FALSE
```

This will keep it from changing variable names while loading your data (but may cause problems downstream if you have undesirable variable names).